# How do I open a MVC view from the controller they way I would open it from Razor code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, partial-views

New to Razor and asp.net MVC, so please take it easy on me.  I'm editing a web site created by someone else.

I need to open a view from a controller.  This view is the home page for my web site, so there's no model for it; there's no information being populated on the page.  The view is originally opened from a menu where the Razor code looks like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
      "Application Summary"
    , "MerchantApplicationSummary"
    , "Admin"
    , new { session = 1 }
    , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get" }
)
```

How do I open the same view, MerchantApplicationSummary, from the .cs controller?

I've been opening views from the controller like this:

```
return View("Application", obj_App);
```

, but when I try that I get an error message:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PagedList.IPagedList`1[CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelMerchantSummary]'.

Can some one show me how to open the view from the controller?  Thank you!

Comment: Your view declares `PagedList.IPagedList1[CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelMerchantSummary]` as its model. But you are trying to use the view with a model of type `CarmelFinancialWeb.Models.ModelApplication`. You'll need a new view to match your model or change the model (`obj_App`) you pass the the view.

Comment: Show us the code of the view. This error basically says you have a @model declaration up top even though you say you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this link:

```
@Html.ActionLink(
      "Application Summary"
    , "MerchantApplicationSummary"
    , "Admin"
    , new { session = 1 }
    , new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Get" }
)
```

"Application Summary" : is the link text
"MerchantApplicationSummary" : is the action
"Admin" : is the controller
new { session = 1 } : is the route arguments

Use the [RedirectToAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311(v=vs.118).aspx) method instead of View, like this

```
var routeData = new RouteData();
routeData.Values.Add("session", "1");

return RedirectToAction("MerchantApplicationSummary", "Admin", routeData);
```

The [RouteData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routedata(v=vs.110).aspx) should be found in the System.Web.Routing namespace in the System.Web.dll.

Comment: Thanks tlaramie.  Looks like this may work, but I get a message saying that RouteData is undefined.  Is there a library besides system.web.mvc I need to include?

Comment: I editted the answer above.  But you might use the [RouteValueDictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505283(v=vs.100).aspx) instead

Comment: Thank you.  I just had to add System.Web.Routing and it worked.  Thanks again for your help tlaramie!